# spring fail to start in tomcat because of Class not found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea, classnotfoundexception

I'm starting to learn javaweb and chose to use SpringMVC+Spring+MyBatis.
spring+mybatis can run locally with no problem,I can get correct print from Jnuit Test

I'm using jdk1.8 and Intellij Idea.

[Here is the screenshot of My Artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar82t.png)

Before I add spring configuration into web.xml,tomcat can run successfully and display index.jsp.

But after line7-57 added,tomcat failed to start.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<!-- configuration file for Spring&mybatis -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring-mybatis.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- coding filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Spring Listener -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- prevent memory Spring -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener</listener-class>
</listener>

 <!--Spring MVC servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Here is the last lines Output of tomcat

```
Connected to server
[2016-05-02 04:51:41,122] Artifact StocksAnalysisSystem:Web exploded:                         Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
MAY 02, 2016 4:51:43 afternoon org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
ERROR: Error configuring application listener of class         org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1858)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:486)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:113)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4984)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1863)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1471)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1312)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1404)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:832)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

MAY 02, 2016 4:51:43 afternoon org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
ERROR: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1858)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:486)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:113)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4984)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1863)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1471)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1312)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1404)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:832)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

May 02, 2016 4:51:43 afternoon org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
Error: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
May 02, 2016 4:51:43 afternoon org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Error: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
May 02, 2016 4:51:43 afternoon org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Error: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
[2016-05-02 04:51:43,776] Artifact StocksAnalysisSystem:Web exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
May 02, 2016 4:51:50 afternoon org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory F:\tomcat\webapps\manager
May 02, 2016 4:51:50 afternoon org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory F:\tomcat\webapps\manager has finished in 124 ms
```

POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project ……>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>StocksAnalysisSystem</groupId>
    <artifactId>StocksAnalysisSystem</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>

        <spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>

        <mybatis.version>3.2.6</mybatis.version>

        <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>collections</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>lang</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/ezmorph-1.0.6.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.python</groupId>
            <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1b2</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jython-standalone-2.7.1b2.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>control</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/controlsfx-8.40.10.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jsoup-1.8.3.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>

            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>${mybatis.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.30</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.41</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>presentation.Starter</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>presentation.Starter</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>net.sf.json</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>beanutils</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.0</version>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                </artifactItem>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>net.sf.json</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>collections</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.0</version>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                </artifactItem>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>net.sf.json</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>lang</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.0</version>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                </artifactItem>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>net.sf.json</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>logging</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.0</version>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                </artifactItem>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>net.sf.json</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.0</version>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                </artifactItem>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>net.sf.json</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>lib</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.0</version>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                </artifactItem>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.python</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
                                    <version>2.7.1b2</version>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                </artifactItem>

                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
                <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: where is log? can you post your full stack trace of your exception?

Comment: @subbu royal Sorry to spend lots of time finding the detailed log,finding the 'edit' button,and edit the question

Answer (score 0):

add below dependency to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: it has already exists and I have checked it by mvn dependency:tree

Comment: can you please post your `pom.xml`?

Comment: try to `clean build` your project

Comment: update before I saw your comment,pom.xml has been added

Comment: clean build ur project

Comment: @ChristineZXZ still getting same exception?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Spring MVC DispatcherServlet, you have to add Spring Web MVC dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

spring-webmvc is transitively dependent on spring-web, so you don't need to add it explicitly.

Comment: it has already exists and I have checked it by mvn dependency:tree:)

Comment: Is this jar being exported to the classes directory under WEB-INF inside .war file?